# Might modifications to scripts in "/etc/gdm3/" be overwritten by updates?

Tags: upgrade, gdm

I modified `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default`. Is there a risk that a GDM update will revert my changes?

This is especially of interest because the systems with the modified scripts run unattended upgrades. Users will not be able to notice if something reverted the changes.

Answer (score 5):

No, modifications to files in `/etc` ("conffiles") will not be automatically overwritten by `dpkg` (see [the Debian Policy 5.1. *Automatic handling of configuration files by dpkg*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html#automatic-handling-of-configuration-files-by-dpkg)). Typically, you'll be prompted on how to handle the situation (choose your version or the package version or something else), and in any case `dpkg` will save a backup. If unattended, or your version was picked, then the package version is saved with a `.dpkg-new` extension, or if the package version was preferred, then the existing one is saved with a `.dpkg-old` extension.

Comment: This means, in the unattended case, my own version will always be preferred and there will be a `.dpkg-new` version, right?